# Can a pawn that performed an en passant capture promote at all?

Tags: pawns, pawn-promotion, en-passant

So let's say I capture en passant with a pawn. Using the same pawn, I get to the 8th rank. Can I promote that pawn into anything else? I've heard of this restriction in various ways. Some say it can become a rook at best, and some say it just stays as a pawn, but it moves backwards.

Please let me know if this is a classic case of "I'm losing better make some stuff," or an actual rule.

Answer (score 23):

From FIDE rules ([3.7 e](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook?id=124&view=article)):

> When a pawn reaches the rank furthest from its starting position it must be exchanged as part of the same move on the same square for a new queen, rook, bishop or knight of the same colour. The player’s choice is not restricted to pieces that have been captured previously. This exchange of a pawn for another piece is called ‘promotion’ and the effect of the new piece is immediate.

There is no restrictions whatsoever about capturing en passant.

Answer (score 8):

For as long as I can remember, there has never been a rule like that in any official matter. The pawn captures en passant and lately it can promote like any other pawn.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a pawn has made an en passant capture does not alter or limit its capabilities at all, including its ability to promote to a queen or other piece when it reaches the eighth rank.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing changes whatsoever to the pawn. It can still promote to a queen, rook, bishop, or knight.

Comment: This question was answered a year ago.

Comment: @Brandon_J why does that matter?

Comment: Well, your post adds little to no value to the site. You introduce no ideas or methods of explanation that weren't already present in the other 3 answers.

Comment: It doesn't add any harm and maybe another way of explaining the concept could be helpful to someone.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the two downvotes for my answer, other than it being a year late?